# How to remove hashtag from the url?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

```
import router from './router'

Vue.use(router)    

new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      template: '<App/>',
      components: { App }
    })
```

I have this piece of code in my main.js and in other file called index.js I have all the paths of the components. I would like to know how to remove the hash from the url. Any docs?? Im using webpack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure your router with mode = history

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Note that your backend should be updated accordingly to serve the other routes as well.

Comment: import routes from './router/index.js'

const router = new VueRouter({
   routes: routes,
   mode: 'history'
 })

And I got this message on the de tools "Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__router__.a is not a constructor"

Answer (score 0):

The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode.
Copied from the `vue-router` [document](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html), we must configure the server (apache, nginx or others) to make sure the `index.html` can be matched, or it will get 404.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I followed the instructions from the documentation but still this error...

"Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__router__.a is not a constructor"

Comment: There must be some mistakes. Here is my code, the router: ```import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';Vue.use(VueRouter) ``` and export your router.  But in your code ```import router from './router'; Vue.use(router)  ``` It was wrong, Vue.use(VuePlugin). Or you show your code, package.json & main.js &router.js

Comment: This is my main:
`
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css'
import vSelect from 'vue-select'
import routes from './router/index.js'

Vue.use(Router)
Vue.use(VueMaterial)

const router = new Router({
  routes: routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})`

as you can see importing the routing file (index.js) into the main

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Vue.Js, you will have to add the `mode: 'history'` line for the new router.
    Vue.use(Router)

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
       ...
    ]
})
```